# Get style value of selection in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor's editing capabilities, but with my own ui controls that calls into CKEditor's api to perform its commands. E.g.,

```
var style = new CKEDITOR.style({
    element: 'span',
    attributes: {
        'style': 'font-size: 20px'
    }
});

editor.applyStyle(style);
```

to set the font size of the selected text.

Problem is that I need a way to know the status of the currently selected text so I can update the controls accordingly. Is it bold? Then the bold button should be in an activated state, and clicking it should remove the boldness instead of attempting to add it again.

Is there a way to query CKEditor for certain style attributes of the currently selected text? Much like how `tinymce.activeEditor.queryCommandValue('bold')` works in tinyMCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the best way to create a button-command-style trio is like it is done in the [basicstyles](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/basicstyles/plugin.js#L16) plugin:

```
var style = new CKEDITOR.style( { ... } );

editor.attachStyleStateChange( style, function( state ) {
    !editor.readOnly && editor.getCommand( 'commandName' ).setState( state );
} );

editor.addCommand( 'commandName', new CKEDITOR.styleCommand( style ) );

editor.ui.addButton( 'buttonName', {
    label: 'buttonLabel',
    command: 'commandName'
} );
```

This code will take care of everything - the command and the button state will be updated according to selection changes. You can also get the command state easily:

```
editor.getCommand( 'commandName' ).state; // Returns on of CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_*.
```

However, if you want to query the state of the style directly, then you can use the [`style.checkActive()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.style-method-checkActive) method:

```
style.checkActive( editor.elementPath(), editor );
```

You don't need to create command and buttons for this to work.

### Edit

The CKEditor styles system has its limitations. For example, you cannot have variable font size in the style. This means that to check the current font size you need to do a quick search in the DOM:

```
function getFontSize() {
    var span = editor.elementPath().contains( isFontSizeSpan );

    return span ? span.getStyle( 'font-size' ) : null;

    function isFontSizeSpan( el ) {
        return el.is( 'span' ) && el.getStyle( 'font-size' );
    }
}
```

Now, just use this method in an [`editor#selectionChange`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-selectionChange) event listener to update your control's value.

Comment: I'd definitely prefer using a built-in system instead of hacking my own together. But I can't see how the above can support free use of, say, an unknown font size. The user types in some number, hits enter, and I take that number and apply it to the selected text. Can it do that? How?

Comment: The style instance represents the concrete style. So there is one style instance per every font size and you need to check each of them to find the applied one.

Comment: Remarkable how difficult it is to build something that gives the user complete freedom over font size.

This means that what I'm trying to do is impossible? I can't ask CKEditor what the fontsize is (so as to show it in a input field for him to edit). Am I correct?

Comment: If you want to give user a full freedom, then you can use the `CKEDITOR.style` to apply or remove the span, but you need to look for current font size in the DOM. To do that just search through `editor.elementPath()` for a right span using for example the [`contains()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.elementPath-method-contains) method (it accepts a callback) and check what size it applies.